# When popup window is closed, the parent window will be focused

Tags: javascript

I have a button inside the parent window that will open the popup window.

If the user closes the popup window, the parent window should get the window focus.

How can I do this in vanilla javascript?

```
function Popup(url, title, w, h) {
    var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;
    var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;
    var newWindow = window.open(url, title, 'scrollbars=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);

    if (window.focus) {
        newWindow.focus();
    }

    newWindow.onunload = function() {
        if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {
            window.opener.focus();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: where you struck? code?

Comment: @shas I have updated my post and included my code. Currently I am using the newWindow.onunload but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the "parent window" has an `HTMLElement` that can be focused, you can use [.focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) on that `HTMLElement`.

Comment: Hi. I have update my post. Do you mind if you can see your solution is applicable on my current code?

Comment: That seems like it would work although I am a little unsure as to why `if (window.opener)` is needed because `window.opener` will always be the `newWindow`.